# Macbook underlines characters - how to get rid of it

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

just bought my first macbook. There's a problem with few characters as they're being underlined and it has strange behavior:

If i type single quote, it gets underlined and if I press other letter, it integrates together, for ex.
I want to type `There's` so I type `There'` and press <kbd>s</kbd> but it becomes `Thereś`. If I press <kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> it becomes `There's`

Underlining looks like this

[image]

Thanks

**EDIT:**
as it was marked as duplicate I found out that changin layout to U.S. may help. But I want to use my native layout not U.S. one - any solution?

Comment: What is you native keyboard?

Comment: It's Czech (few more symbols so I can post this comment)

Comment: Ah ok, no solution really you're using a keyboard setting that has fixed dead keys so what you want is two conflicting settings ie. you're asking for the keyboard to be aware of your "intention" not your actions. :D The only thing I can think of is setting a shortcut to swap keyboard modes but that isn't really going to help.